# this code gives an error with the else statement , what correctiions do i need to make to allow the code work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function range(start, end, step) {
  var array = [];
  if (step < 0) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i -= step) {
      array.push(i);
    };
    return array;
  };
  else if (step > 0) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
      array.push(i);
    };
    return array;
  };
  else {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      array.push(i);
    };
    return array;
  };
};
};
```

Comment: What kind of error are you facing? Can you share a runnable example that triggers the problem?

Comment: Remove the `; ` after the `}`

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra bracket at the end of the function.

Also, you need to remove the `;` after each if / else if / else end brackets

```js
function range(start, end, step) {
  var array = [];
  if (step < 0) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i -= step) {
      array.push(i);
    };
    return array;
  } else if (step > 0) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
      array.push(i);
    };
    return array;
  } else {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
  }
};

console.log(range(0, 100, 2))
```